# Visual C++ 2013 - Windows XP Sp1 C Program Not Working - Blank Command Line

Tags: c++, c, windows, visual-studio-2013, windows-xp

just created and compiled a simple "Hello world" in C in Visual Studio 2013 for testing purpose as some service I wrote didn't work on a Windows XP machine (yes I know it's ultra old, never mind).

So I thought I'd test with "hello world". I know that I need to select a Windows XP compatible environment in the General Settings of the Visual Studio project, done that. Tried MT and MD, so static or dynamic. Both gives me the same result: Nothing. Just a blank command line. I don't get it.

Any ideas what might be missing? I'm afraid I don't have full access on the XP system, just a command line shell, that's it. But I guess that wouldn't make a real difference.

I tried other command line tools which tend to work just fine, just my own compiled ones do nothing. Source code, just so noone asks ;-)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("Hello World\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Hm...aaaannoying:-)

Comment: vs2013 prompt? Could you,...explain further? I have no VS2013 on that said XP machine,...

Comment: From [MS website](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-2013-compatibility-vs.aspx) it looks that XP is supported, but it requires `Update 2 or later`. Additionally you probably need SP3 to be installed (see footnote 1).

Comment: Ahhh, cool. Or not so cool. Any idea how XP pre SP2 can be supported?oO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, funny, as Ganesh R. rightly pointed out: It does not work with Visual Studio 2013 anymore.

So I switched to Mingw and,...perfect!

Answer (score 1):

1. The platform toolset should be set to XP in your project.
2. The [VC++ 2013 runtime](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=40784) should be present on the test machine.
3. Build in release mode. Else you will have to copy the VC++ debug dlls to your applications bin folder while deploying on to the test machine

   4. Set the _win32_winnt preprocessor to XP i.e. #define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501

[image]

Comment: Points 1. and 3. are already done.

When I link statically, (MT), point 2. should not be necessary, should it? If so: Any way to prevent that?

Comment: Can you try without statically linking and installing VC++ runtime? If that works you can try out statically linked

Comment: Also make sure that you set the _win32_winnt preprocessor to XP i.e. #define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501

Comment: Nope, I can't install anything there,...:-/